# Relational joining of tables

Tags: list-manipulation

A common thing to want to do with data is to combine it (at least I thought this was a common thing). In SQL there is the idea of table joins "select id,v1,v2 from A,B where A.id=B.id" kind of thing. I'm trying to do a join like this using Mathematica, i.e. retrieve table A from the Internet, retrieve table B from the Internet, combine, do stuff with the resulting joined columns.

My First effort was this:

```
(* Simulate tables *)
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}];
(* Use this simple match function for now *)
RMatch[x_] := x[[1]] == x[[3]];
Length[Part[
   Select[Flatten[Outer[Function[{x, y}, Join[x, y]], a, b, 1], 1], 
    RMatch], All, {1, 2, 4}]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.906250, 1000}
> ```

This works, but is way too slow. Imagine if it was 100,000 rows each; the program may never finish. Also this will take up a lot of memory; creating a temporary list of rows that is NxM in size.

So I tried an iterative approach instead:

```
(* Simulate tables *)
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}];
(* Use this simple match function for now *)
RMatch[x_, y_] := x[[1]] == y[[1]];
RJoin[a_, b_, match_] := Block[
  {lena = Length[a], lenb = Length[b], arow, brow, i, j},
  Flatten[Reap[
     For[i = 1, i <= lena, ++i,
      arow = a[[i]];
      For[j = 1, j <= lenb, ++j,
       brow = b[[j]];
       If[match[arow, brow], Sow[Join[arow, brow]]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ][[2]], 1
   ]
  ]
Length[Select[RJoin[a, b, RMatch], 
   Function[{x}, x[[1]] == x[[3]]]]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {2.562500, 1000}
> ```

This will use much less memory, but is even slower.

Is this something that just isn't appropriate for *Mathematica* i.e. do this using a different tool, output the table and work with that instead?  That would be a shame, but it seems that it may be necessary.

## Update:

Thanks to the great answers below I decided to give up on the general case and focus on unique ID matching, which is the situation that arises the most. Following [Verbeia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32013/7115) and [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32016/7115)'s examples I came up with a version that is fast and readable.

```
(* Simulate tables *)
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000000, 2}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000000, 3}];

RJoin[a_, b_] := Block[{f},
  Do[
    f[x[[1]]] = x[[2]],
    {x, a}
    ];
   Cases[b /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, f[x]}, {_, _, _Real}]
  ]

(* Use and time *)
Length[RJoin[a, b]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.750000, 166667}
> ```

That's 1.75 seconds to join two tables with almost a million rows total. This is mildly faster than [Michael E](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32016/7115)'s version which took 4.2 seconds on my computer.

When I need a more general case I plan to use Java to process the data, but this should handle most of my cases.

## Update 2

I managed to simplify and speed up the arbitrary matching case a little bit

```
(*Simulate tables*)
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000, 1}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000, 1}];

(*Use this simple match function for now*)
RMatch[x_, y_] := x[[1]] == y[[1]];

RJoin[a_, b_, match_] :=
 Flatten[
  Reap[Do[
      If[match[x, y],
       Sow[{x[[1]], x[[2]], y[[2]]}];
       ],
      {x, a}, {y, b}
      ];
    ][[2]]
  , 1]
Length[RJoin[a, b, RMatch]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.359375, 1000}
> ```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/vlookup-function-as-excel-in-mathematica)?

Comment: I think the difference is that this one (I think) assumes unique keys. At least that's what I understand a SQL table id to be.

Comment: I'm not assuming unique keys. I'm not assuming 'keys' at all. I'm want to be able to apply an arbitrary condition. My example is just that - an example. Imagine a condition like measuring distance between two points and selecting those below a certain limit. That kind of arbitrary and flexible thing. This is no big deal for relational databases for hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Murta - I think that question and answer can be applied to my situation. Hopefully you can forgive me for not seeing "Vlookup function as Excel in Mathematica" as being the same as my question. I would never think to search for such a thing.

Comment: Well, the question was written in terms of things with matching id's, so please forgive me that it was not clear to me that you had something more general in mind. But different criteria would suggest a different approach, including your `Outer` one.

Comment: Verbeia - I thank you for your great answer. It is very fast. For the general case I think I have to conclude that Mathematica is not suitable. It is not meant to do fast loops. I think (personal opinion here) that this might be the curse of a Functional programming languages in general. When there is a built-in Function that does what you want, the solution is usually concise (if not always clear - in fact it is seldom clear). When there is not, then you are best to use a different language.

Comment: @IanSchumacher - on the contrary - it is just that there are plenty of cases where people versed in other languages would reach for a loop, but vectorised or pattern-matching operations would be more efficient. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8).

Comment: Some interesting thoughts [here](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/m_performance/m_performance.html) about why loops aren't usually the best way to program Mathematica.

Comment: Note that in your timing of the update, you did not include the time it takes to initialize `f`, which takes 2-3 times as long as the `Cases` part.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Oh. Whoops! Updated results and text :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is fairly fast.  I used `GatherBy` to collect like data rows and kept the ones that matched another.  (I assumed that the `id` entries of `a` and `b` are unique in each table.)  The appropriate entries are then extracted.

On 10000/5000 entries:

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000, 2}];
Flatten[Cases[GatherBy[a~Join~b, First], {_, _}], {{1}, {2, 3}}][[All, {1, 2, 4}]] //
  Timing // First
(* 0.014554 *)
```

On 100,000/50,000 entries (roughly linear growth):

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 100000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 100000, 2}];
Flatten[Cases[GatherBy[a~Join~b, First], {_, _}], {{1}, {2, 3}}][[All, {1, 2, 4}]] //
  Timing // First
(* 0.175955 *)
```

The output on a small data set looks like this:

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10, 2}];
Flatten[Cases[GatherBy[a~Join~b, First], {_, _}], {{1}, {2, 3}}][[All, {1, 2, 4}]]
(* {{1, 0.74066, 0.69329}, {3, 0.80351, 0.420397}, {5, 0.239924, 0.806693},
    {7, 0.665209, 0.0483077}, {9, 0.705487, 0.737412}} *)
```

By comparison Verbeia's version is roughly of quadratic growth and rather slower:

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000, 2}];
(Join[{##}, Cases[b, {#1, _}][[All, 2]]] & @@@ a) /. {_, _} -> Sequence[] //
  Timing // First
(* 0.065370 *)

a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000, 2}];
(Join[{##}, Cases[b, {#1, _}][[All, 2]]] & @@@ a) /. {_, _} -> Sequence[] //
  Timing // First
(* 5.736539 *)
```

### Update

Below I present two faster functions, based on a similar idea: if the data `Join[a, b]` were sorted on the IDs, rows to be joined would end up next to each other.  I used [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html) and [`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Differences.html) to determine the rows with the same ID.  When sorted, a difference in IDs of zero indicates two rows to be joined.  `SparseArray` and `ArrayReshape` seem fairly fast here, but they're not [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).  For the compiled version, `Position` and `Partition` were used instead.  On packed arrays, both have comparable speeds.

I avoid sorting the whole database, since moving all that memory around will take time.

I'm assuming that the IDs are numeric.  Indeed, to get the speed below, the data have to be numeric.  The speed is dependent on using packed arrays.  The compiled function assumes the IDs can be represented by `Real` numbers.

```
mJoin2[a_, b_] := 
  With[{data = a ~Join~ b,
        ids = a[[All, 1]] ~Join~ b[[All, 1]],
        ncols = Last @ Dimensions @ a},
   With[{ordering = Ordering[ids]}, 
    With[{adj = SparseArray[1 - Unitize @ Differences @ ids[[ordering]]]["AdjacencyLists"]},
     ArrayReshape[
        data[[ ordering[[Flatten @ Transpose @ {#, # + 1} &@ adj]] ]],
        {Length @ adj, 4}
      ][[All, Join[Range@ncols, Range[2 + ncols, 2 ncols]]]]
     ]]];

mJoin3 = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}, {b, _Real, 2}},
   Module[{data, ids, ordering, joinID, ncols},
    data = a ~Join~ b;
    ids = a[[All, 1]] ~Join~ b[[All, 1]];
    ncols = Last @ Dimensions @ a;
    ordering = Ordering[ids];
    joinID = Flatten @ Position[Unitize @ Differences @ ids[[ordering]], 0];
    Partition[
      Flatten[
       data[[
         Flatten @ Transpose @ {ordering[[joinID]], ordering[[1 + joinID]]}
         ]]],
      2 ncols
      ][[All, Join[Range @ ncols, Range[2 + ncols, 2 ncols]]]]
    ]
   ];
```

**Comparison**

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

a = Table[{N@x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 2000000, 3}];
b = Table[{N@x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 2000000, 2}];

(m3 = mJoin3[a, b]) // Length // Timing     (* Michael E2 compiled *)
(m2 = mJoin2[a, b]) // Length // Timing     (* Michael E2 SparseArray method *)
(m1 = Flatten[                              (* Michael E2 original *)
       Cases[GatherBy[a~Join~b, First], {_, _}], {{1}, {2, 3}}][[All, {1, 2, 4}]]) //
         Length // Timing
(i2 = RJoin[b, a]) // Length // Timing      (* Ian S. -- first update *)
```

> {0.177294, 333334}
>   {0.210489, 333334}
>   {2.890227, 333334}
>   {5.517205, 333334}

```
m1 == m2 == m3 == i2
(* True *)
```

On non-packed arrays `mJoin2` slows down.  The compiled function `mJoin3` converts the `Integer` indices to `Real` and packs the arrays when it is called, which causes a slight slowdown.

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 2000000, 3}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 2000000, 2}];

(m3 = mJoin3[a, b]) // Length // Timing
(m2 = mJoin2[a, b]) // Length // Timing
```

> {0.220412, 333334}
>   {0.580442, 333334}

Note: My original solution can be a bit of a memory hog.  I believe it was slower in Ian Schumacher's test because it filled the RAM and led to some swapping.

Comment: Oh even better! And much better complexity growth behavior as well, which I neglected to investigate for Verbeia's answer.

Comment: Clever. Good approach. Gives me more ideas.

Comment: Really nice use of `Ordering` here.  I wonder if there is an efficient way to apply it to [your own question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121).  Although it makes little overall difference `Flatten[{adj, adj + 1}, {2, 1}]` is faster than `Flatten @ Transpose @ {#, # + 1} &@ adj` BTW.

Answer (score 4):

I might have misunderstood what it is you are trying to do, but I would have thought that `Cases` would be a better option, and that looping approach was not ideal.

Here is a one-liner that seems to do what I think you want. Firstly, if you are looking for an index that is in both lists, then you only need to iterate over one list and find the indices that are also present in the other list.

Here is a better test dataset, since not all of the indices in `a` are in `b`.

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000}]; 
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 1000, 2}];
```

And here is my function:

```
(Join[{##}, Cases[b, {#1, _}][[All, 2]]] & @@@ a) /. 
  {_, _} ->   Sequence[]
```

This goes through each element of `a` and selects all the elements of `b` that have the same index (first part), and keeps only the second part, which is the value. That's what the `Part` specification `[[All,2]]` is doing. I `Join` that with the corresponding actual `a` element, and then delete, using a replacement rule, the ones that are only two  elements long, since that means that no element of `b` actually matched.

I tested it on the long dataset above and got the following output:

```
{{1, 0.177197, 0.569452}, {3, 0.980658, 0.544697}, {5, 0.507622, 
  0.634173}, {7, 0.645986, 0.820293}, {9, 0.215669, 0.803831}, {11, 
  0.460078, 0.293823}, {13, 0.520429, 0.813139}, {15, 0.679199, 
  0.48138}...
```

It took about 0.1 seconds on my three-year-old PC.

Comment: This looks interesting for cases where I want to join on an ID. I'll look at it more. I would also like to handle arbitrary join conditions, but joining on an ID is very common and useful of course. I'll keep it in the toolkit for those cases for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @IanSchumacher this solution is more appropriate for a left. Using vLookup3 from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18722/2266) we have:

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000, 2}];
vLookup3[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.041213

for a inner join you can do:

```
DeleteCases[vLookup3[a, b],{__,Null}]
```

Comment: This give many nulls (i.e. it appears to be a left outer join rather than the desired inner join). I ran this with x,1,1000000,2 and x,1,1000000,3 and measuring the time and length I got {2.015625, 500000}, which is what I would expect for a left outer join that results in nulls. It's very fast, but still slightly slower than the solution I posted that does an inner join. Maybe you can alter it to have it do an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

Using and `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Flatten[Reap[Join[Map[Sow @@ Reverse[#] &, {a, b}, {2}]], Intersection[b[[All, 1]],a[[All,1]]],
    Join[{#1}, #2] &][[2]], 1]
```

Uses the first column as tags and elements with common tags are "reaped". Try Verbeia's test data.

Comment: Nice, but there seems to be an error. Try a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 100, 2}]; b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 100, 3}]; for example.

Comment: @IanSchumacher thank you. I have corrected the code to deal with this, i.e intersection (common) identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Using the function SelectEquivalents defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245166)

```
a = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000}];
b = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10000, 2}];

SelectEquivalents[{a,b},
    MapLevel->2,
    TagElement->First,
    TransformElement->(#[[2]]&),
    TransformResults->(Join[{#1},#2]&),
    FinalFunction->(Select[#,Length@#>2&]&)
]//Timing//First

 (*0.11*)
```

This can have the advantage to be reusable and adaptable to a variety of cases (once you understand the SelectEquivalents function, use Print for this), as the different important operations are separate.

Comment: Interesting. Worth studying. I tried it with a million data points (using //Length //Timing and offsets of 2 and 3 to have a fair comparison with my results). It took 38 seconds on my machine. Quite usable, but not the current performance winner.