# Using Semantic Import to do an Excel-like VLookUp using Mathematica

Tags: import, dataset, query, semantic-matching

I'm following an example provided in the following

[Stack Exchange Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/vlookup-function-as-excel-in-mathematica)

but, using a different approach.  My data is contained in an Excel workbook called "Input Workbook.xlsx" 
as shown here:

[image: Excel workbook image]

I define my working directory as follows:

```
setDir := Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

path = FileNameJoin[{setDir, "Input Workbook.xlsx"}]
```

I define my first and second tables as follows:

```
firsttable = SemanticImport[path, <|"Wine" -> Automatic, "Brand" -> Integer|>, HeaderLines -> 1]

secondtable = SemanticImport[path, <|"Brands" -> Integer, "Color" -> String, "Bouquet" -> String|>, HeaderLines -> 1] // Take[#, 5] &


rls = Append[# :> {##2} & @@@ Normal[secondtable], _ -> {None, None}] // Dispatch
```

But, then I have to make the following extra steps to get the final output table (with the column headings):

```
wine = Lookup[Normal[firsttable], "Wine"]

brand = Lookup[Normal[firsttable], "Brand"]

need = Transpose[{wine, brand}]

ds = Dataset[Join[need, Replace[Normal[firsttable[[All, 2]]], rls, {1}], 2]]

finaltable = ds[All, <|"Wine" -> 1, "Brand" -> 2, "Color" -> 3, "Bouquet" -> 4|>]
```

The point that I'm making is that the above semantic imports should facilitate performing the VLookUp but, somehow; introducing
the keys (i.e.; "Wine", Brand", "Brands", "Color", "Bouquet") complicate matters.  There must be a much straight-forward way to do a VLookUp when Semantic Import and keys are used.  Can anyone show me a better way?  Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an example dataset that can be easily copied, together with the expected output. Also, is any of the code in the question necessary to answer the question? (i.e. do we need to know how the dataset is generated, or do you only care about how to do a given query on the final dataset?)

Comment: Just a note, there's no need to use `SetDirectory` in `setDir`. That might cause you grief in the future and you can just use the `path` you have.

Comment: I don't have a website to make the input Excel workbook available @Lukas Lang.  That's why I inserted the image of the workbook above; the dataset can be easily built using Excel.  The "SetDir" and "path" are necessary and are not a source of trouble b3m2a1.  Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate on what a VLookup actually is - what the functionality you want to see is.

Comment: The Excel VLookup functionalty was described in the Stack Exchange link that I provided at the beginning of my request @Carl Lange.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: My apologies, I didn't look closely enough. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Carl Lange No need to apologize my friend.  On the contrary; your feedback is a privilege to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   setDir := Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

   path = FileNameJoin[{setDir, "Input Workbook.xlsx"}]

   firsttable = SemanticImport[path, <|"Wine" -> Automatic, "Brand" ->  Integer|>, HeaderLines -> 1]

   secondtable = SemanticImport[path, <|"Brands" -> Integer, "Color" -> String, "Bouquet" -> String|>, HeaderLines -> 1] // Take[#, 5] &

   thirdtable = SortBy[Dataset[JoinAcross[firsttable, secondtable, "Brand" -> "Brands", "Left"] ], First]

   finaltable = thirdtable[All, {"Wine", "Brand", "Color", "Bouquet"}] /. 
   Missing["Unmatched"] -> "None"
```